# Why can't the function give the numerical value?

Tags: numerics, output

Beginner at *Mathematica*, I cant figure it out how to obtain numerical result from my defined function "Temp[t]". When I run the program, I end up getting the whole expression in terms of variable $t$. I tried using `N[exp]` function but no use. I also need to use the table function to store a list of outputs but no output is being produced.
What is going wrong?

```
ClearAll[t];
q=15;
k=2.59;
r=0.125;
a=9.7*10^(-7);
H0=80;
d1=80;
h=H0/Sqrt[4*a*t];
d=d1/Sqrt[4*a*t];
w=d*Erf[d]-(1-Exp[-d^2])/Sqrt[Pi];
x=(2*h+2*d)*Erf[2*h+2*d]-(1-Exp[-(2*h+2*d)^2])/Sqrt[Pi];
y=(h+2*d)*Erf[h+2*d]-(1-Exp[-(h+2*d)^2])/Sqrt[Pi];
z=h*Erf[h]-(1-Exp[-h^2])/Sqrt[Pi];
i=2*z+2*y-x-w;
Temp[t_]:=(q/4*Pi*k*H0)*Exp[-r^2/(4*a*t)]*i*Sqrt[a/t]
N[Temp[2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to fix the problem of `temp[2]` returning an expression involving `t` (thanks @JackLaVigne) is to use `=` (`Set`) rather than `:=` (`SetDelayed`) in your definition of `temp`. So restart the kernel and do everything the same up to and including the definition of `i`, and then

```
temp[t_] = FullSimplify[(q/4*Pi*k*H0)*Exp[-r^2/(4*a*t)]*i*Sqrt[a/t]];
```

(The `FullSimplify` is needed because evaluations seem to hang without it... `Simplify`ing is often a good idea, just on principle.)

Then

```
temp[2]
```

> 5.0159*10^-870

and

```
Plot[temp[t], {t, 0, 5 10^4}]
```

[image]

Comment: That `FullSimplify` sure makes a difference. Without it, my system eventually hung when memory usage suddenly shot to 99%.

Comment: @aardvark Compute the `FullSimplify[q...` . Copy the output and equate `temp[t_]:= <copy>`. Works fine. It is mis-leading to blame the problem on `SetDelayed`. It is really the `FullSimplify` that is the source of the speed up.

Comment: @JackLaVigne As far as I could tell, there were two problems. One was that, with `:=`, `temp[2]` was returning an expression involving `t`. The other was the hanging/speed problem. The first was due to not having `t` explicit on rhs of the def of `temp`. `FullSimplify` by itself would not solve that - it only fixes the speed. Your copy and paste method solves both problems in one go. I certainly didn't mean to imply that the hanging problem was due to `SetDelayed`.

Comment: @JackLaVigne I have edited the answer to (hopefully) make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`h` and `d` are functions of `t`, and hence should be defined with the same `[t_] :=` `SetDelayed` pattern-matching as you use with `Temp`. Your code above does not know to replace the `t`s with the value `2`.

Then `w,x,y,z`, being functions of `h` and `d`, are indirectly functions of `t`, and should also be defined with the `SetDelayed` pattern-matching. After making those changes you would have

```
h[t_] := H0/Sqrt[4*a*t];
d[t_] := d1/Sqrt[4*a*t];
w[t_] := d[t]*Erf[d[t]] - (1 - Exp[-d[t]^2])/Sqrt[Pi];
x[t_] := (2*h[t] + 2*d[t])*
    Erf[2*h[t] + 2*d[t]] - (1 - Exp[-(2*h[t] + 2*d[t])^2])/Sqrt[Pi];
y[t_] := (h[t] + 2*d[t])*
    Erf[h[t] + 2*d[t]] - (1 - Exp[-(h[t] + 2*d[t])^2])/Sqrt[Pi];
z[t_] := h[t]*Erf[h[t]] - (1 - Exp[-h[t]^2])/Sqrt[Pi];
i[t_] := 2*z[t] + 2*y[t] - x[t] - w[t];
temp[t_] := (q/4*Pi*k*H0)*Exp[-r^2/(4*a*t)]*i[t]*Sqrt[a/t];
temp[2]
```

Also, I changed your `Temp` to `temp`; it is generally better to begin your symbols with lowercase letters because built-in Mathematica symbols begin with uppercase letters.

For the table portion, you can `Map` the function over the `Table`

```
temp /@ Table[2 i, {i, 1, 10}]
```

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: Right now-> the program just keeps on running and nothing displays.